# PHP - Assign the numbers 1-3 to an infinite sequence of numbers

Tags: php, math

Ok. Basically I want to assign the numbers 1-3 to an infinite progression of numbers in PHP. How would I do this?

I want to assign as follows.

Core - 1. Supplement - 1.

Core - 2. Supplement - 2.

Core - 3. Supplement - 3.

Core - 4. Supplement - 1.

Core - 5. Supplement - 2.

Core - 6. Supplement - 3.

Core - 7. Supplement - 1.

etc

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) :

```
$num = ($index % 3) + 1
```

will always return a number between 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a basic modulus function.

Modulus is defined as the remainder of a division, and is specified in PHP using the percent sign.

example code:

```
<?php
for($loopcount = 1; $loopcount<=$max; $loopcount++) {
    print "Counter: ".$loopcount." ... Counter mod 3: ".($loopcount % 3)."<br />\n";
}
?>
```

Will give you a sequence of 0,1,2,0,1,2, etc. Just add 1 to the mod result to get 1,2,3,1,2,3 etc.

So to produce exactly as you've asked:

```
<?php
for($loopcount = 1; $loopcount<=$max; $loopcount++) {
    print "Core - ".$loopcount.". Supplement - ".(($loopcount % 3)+1).".<br />\n";
}
?>
```

See the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use a while loop:

```
$arrayNum = array(); //aray of numbers
$max_number = 100; //max of numbers (you can set this to any value)
$i = 0;

while($i < $max_number) {
   $arrayNum[$i] = ($i % 3) + 1; // the +1 ensures that none = 0
   echo "Core - $i. Supplement - {$arrayNum[$i]}"; //echo result
   $i ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$supplement = 1;
$coreMax = 10;

for ($core = 1; $core <= $coreMax; $core++){
    echo "Core - $core. Supplement - $supplement".
    $supplement++;
    if ($supplement > 3){
        $supplement = 1;
    }
}
```